# Calling a phone number from app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a UITableView and I have taken  phonenumber as one of the UILabel in UITableViewCell.When I click on that particular label then I should be able to make a call to that particular number.For UILabel to respond to clicks I took UITapGesture.But in detecting which number to be called I used [sender tag]which throws error:"**[UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  lblphone = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
            lblphone.tag = 116;
            lblphone.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [lblphone setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
            [lblphone setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [lblphone setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelButton:)];
            [tapGestureRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
            [lblphone addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
            [tapGestureRecognizer release];
            [cell addSubview:lblphone];


}

 CGSize constraint5 = CGSizeMake(320, 2000.0f);
                            CGSize size5=[phone sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14] constrainedToSize:constraint5 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                            lblphone =(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:116];
                            [lblphone setFrame:CGRectMake(10,businessname.frame.size.height+businessname.frame.origin.y,320, size5.height)];
                            lblphone.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
                            lblphone.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                            lblphone.numberOfLines=0;
                            lblphone.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByClipping;
                            lblphone.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14];
                            lblphone.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",phone ];
                            [lblphone sizeToFit];
}

-(IBAction)labelButton:(id)sender
{

   selectedrowCall=[sender tag]; //error at this line

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://%@",[lblphone.text]]];//error at this line also :Expected Identifier

}
```

How can I call to that particular number only which is clicked in tableviewcell? I want to confirm whether I will be able to test phonecalling from simulator ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem initially lies with this code:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelButton:)];
```

Where you initialize a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and set its action to `labelButton:` but because you do not specify a parameter and the method `labelButton:` is asking for an `id` argument, a tap gesture recognizer is getting passed into the `labelButton` method instead of a `UIButton` which is why it crashes because `UITapGestureRecognizer` is not able to respond to `tag`, it is not a UI object.

So to fix it its actually pretty easy, use this code:

```
-(IBAction)labelButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   selectedrowCall=[[sender view] tag]; // here we are referencing to sender's view which is the UILabel so it works!
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://%@",[lblphone text]]];    
}
```

If this worked please upvote/tick!